# Unrelated Tags or Tags Not be Confused with?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, tooltips, tag-disambiguation

I'm familiar with at least two sets of tags which often get confused with one another

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com)
- [phaser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser) and [phaser-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser-framework)
- [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) and [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)
- [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)
- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) and [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing)
- (feel free to edit and add a few other examples - I know there are many others)

Often when reviewing suggested edits, I see big groups of edits where one person has gone through the effort of trying to fix all of the mistaggings (today, specifcally the inspiration for this post, it was the [phaser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser) and [phaser-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser-framework) tags.)

I figured that this could be fixed by going into the tag wiki and modifying it to clarify that one shouldn't be confused with the other, but I discovered that, in fact, the tag wiki already had the exact note in it that I would have added! The issue is, it's placed at the end of the wiki such that the note doesn't appear in the tooltip for the tag.

Part of the problem now seems to be a lack of consistency with placing these notes in the tag wiki's. Some wiki's have the note about what not to confuse the tag with at the start of it, while others put such notes at the end (in the case of [phaser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser)) or in the middle (in the case of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)).

So here's my feature request:

I'd like something that's kind of the opposite of tag-synonyms. There should be some standard mechanism for saying that multiple tags shouldn't be confused with one another. The tag tooltip that pops up should make sure to specifically mention those tags which this tag shouldn't be confused with.

Having it be a standard mechanism means that everyone knows how to handle this in the future. There's no more confusion about whether to put the note at the start, end, middle, or anywhere else.

Comment: The only problem with this feature is that it requires the OP to "read" either the tag tooltip or wiki or both, which I speculate is the root of the issue (*People aren't reading the tag information*). I'd like to add [tag:titanium-alloy], [tag:alloy], and [tag:alloy-ui] to this scenario. On several occasions, an OP of `titanium-alloy` will blindly tag a question `alloy` which has a couple of devoted followers who consistently re-tag the questions with `alloy-ui` which I follow. To a lesser degree the `alloy` / `alloy-ui` mistag has occurred.

Comment: You might as well add [tag:c], [tag:c++], and [tag:c#], where the consensus seems to be "when in doubt add all of them". Oh, and the ever-present confusion between [tag:java] and [tag:javascript]. The underlying problem is *people aren't reading the tag information* (well worth repeting!).

Comment: @Jongware: You left out [tag:C++-cli], [tag:managed-c++], [tag:objective-c] and [tag:objectiv-c++] out of that unhappy family (at a minimum).

Comment: I just came across a fun example of where this might help a question on using Parse.com in JavaScript ended up with the tags Java and Parsing. So 2 out of 2 tags that were assigned to the question were incorrect, but commonly mixed up by new users.