# Unity vs Unity3d Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

I feel like everytime I go into the review queues I need to update [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tags to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).  If you look at the tag counts there are more than 3x more [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) questions, and a lot of the[unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) questions are just mistagged [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) questions.

I know that this has been brought up before, but I literally see this every single day.  It seems like it would benefit a lot of users and prevent a lot of duplicate questions.  Is there a reason why this not been addressed yet?  Anything we can do to help out with this renaming process?

A possibility might even to burn the [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag completely due to it being ambiguous and users would have to choose between [unity-ioc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-ioc) or [unity-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-engine) (and others more specific tags) as an example.

Previous discussions about this topic that have died:

- [Replace the misleading [unity] tag with a more distinct tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269701/replace-the-misleading-unity-tag-with-a-more-distinct-tag)
- [Rename [Unity] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287652/rename-unity-tag)
- [Unrelated Tags or Tags Not be Confused with?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274583/unrelated-tags-or-tags-not-be-confused-with)

I think we need to come up with a solution to be since these tags are pretty much useless for proper categorization at this point due to their misuse.  Here are some possible resolutions other than the burnation of the ambigious Unity tag mentioned as a possibility above:

- Repurpose or create a synonym for the the Unity tag to mean Unity-Engine (this will require going through the posts and property checking and retagging as needed)
- The opposite of point 1:  Rename/Synonym the unity tag to unity-container or unity-ioc since that's what it actually means in the first place.  However, unity-engine is more popular on the site, so this wouldn't be my recommendation.
- Create some kind of warning system that will pop up if a user attempts to use an ambiguous tag (nice idea @GoBusto).  This can make the poster confirm if they actually selected the correct tag.  Not sure how difficult this would be to implement though.

I'd be happy to help out on this mission if I can.  I don't yet have the "Create tag synonym" privilege, but other than that if we come up with a plan I'm game to fix this problem once and for all.

Comment: I was thinking about asking this myself after [making](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7498922) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7498928) [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7498950) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7498956) [morning](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7498962). It's an easy mistake to make, if you don't read the [**ALL CAPS**](http://bash.org/?350532) [tag summary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity). It would be nice if a warning was shown if ambiguous tags are added.

Comment: @GoBusto  that would be a good way to handle this.

Comment: @walther I'm aware that it's a duplicate, however none of those have ever actually been resolved.  If you completely read my post you'd see that I even linked to that post in particular, however I'm reopening this because no action has been taken

Comment: @GoBusto I added your suggestion to a list of possibilities in my post.  This is especially common for newbies since they probably don't completely read the tag wikis.  Again this isn't necessarily their fault, but it happens when you're not completely familiar with the site

Comment: @JNYRanger If you're aware of this, why are you posting a new question instead of reviving the old one?

Comment: @BartoszKP Because I'm a meta noob.  Should I have posted an answer in one of those threads suggesting some possible ideas to correct the situation?

Comment: @JNYRanger If these ideas weren't posted already - absolutely. Otherwise you can vote and/or comment :)

Comment: @GoBusto - That proposal seems like the same as what I proposed in my related post (JNYRanger even linked to it within this post): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274583/unrelated-tags-or-tags-not-be-confused-with